# How to handle async in ngOnChanges

Tags: angular

I ran into this issue and I don't see how to treat `async` method because `ngOnChanges` doesn't support `async`.

What do you guys do to make this happen?

It doesn't work when I apply `async` to `ngOnChanges`.  The return value is `Promise`.

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'search',
  templateUrl: 'search.template.html'
})
export class Search implments OnChanges {
  async queryArray(data: string): Promise<T> {
     //sample scripts.
     return ....;
  }
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
     let query: string = "red";
     let result: string[] = [];

     await this.queryArray(query).then(resp => result = resp);
  }
```

}

Comment: can you store the response in the components scope instead of the ngOnChanges scope? await this.queryArrray(query).then(resp => this.result = resp);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Mark the method as `async`
- Add `await` to wait for the result of the `Promise`
- Remove the `then` as now you can assign the result directly once you add the `await`
- Assign the result directly.

Code:

```
async ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   let query: string = "red";
   let result: string[] = [];

   result = await this.queryArray(query);
}
```

Also note that `queryArray` does not need to be marked as `async` unless you want to also await the result in that method for further processing. If all it is doing is creating and returning a Promise then it is not necessary.

Comment: Wow!  That's alot simplier than I thought.  Seems I need a lot more practice on Javascript Promise as I came off from JQuery background.  THanks man!